# Isomorphism of Lie algebras as similarity transformation

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

If two finite dimensional matrix Lie algebras are isomorphic, is it always possible to see the isomorphism as a similarity transformation $g \mapsto M^{-1} g M$ ?

Comment: Are you asking: given two subalgebras $g$ and $g'$ of the matrx algebra $M_n(k)$, is there a matrix $M$ such that $g'=MgM^{-1}$?

Answer (score 2):

If the question is

> given two isomorphic Lie subalgebras $\mathfrak g$, $\mathfrak g'$ of $M_n(k)$, does there exist a matrix $M$ such that $\mathfrak g'=M\mathfrak gM^{-1}$?

then the answer is no. Just take $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak g'$ to be two $1$-dimensional Lie algebras spanned by matrices which are not conjugated.

Comment: In fact, in some sense, the whole theory of representations of Lie algebras gives a ton of examples:  Any two non-equivalent faithful representations of the same dimension give a counter example.

Comment: Is it possible that two non-equivalent faithful representations of the same dimension that are as well irreducible are non equivalent? Is there probably a difference between semisimple or general Lie algebras?

Comment: @user9784 I don't understand the question.